# Database table not being updated

Tags: sql-update

I have been struggling with this piece of code. Everything is being updated except my items table in the database. Need the sales part to be plus 1 each time someone makes a purchase.

```
    $setQuery = '';
    if($extended) {
        $setQuery = " `status` = 'extended_buy', ";
    }

    $mysql->query("
        UPDATE `items`
        SET `sales` = `sales` + 1,
                $setQuery
                `earning` = `earning` + '".sql_quote($price)."'
        WHERE `id` = '".intval($item['id'])."'
    ");     

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Subquery for the same

It would be somewhat like this
SET `sales` = (From items where WHERE `id` = '".intval($item['id']) + 1,

You will need to pull its value and then Add it.
In other case you can pick it in variable and update it.